# rails join only those groups whose all members are 18+

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, join

I have model named `User` with has_many through relation with `Group`
User:

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :user_groups, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :groups, through: :user_groups
end
```

Group:

```
class Group < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :user_groups, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :users, through: :user_groups
end
```

UserGroup:

```
class UserGroup < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :group
end
```

I want to find groups whose all users are 18+.
I tried something like

```
Group.joins(:users).where("users.age >?",18)
```

but its gives duplicate results,

> Like a group named "group A" has 3 users with age 17,20,21 then it
>   returns me "group A" two times, and only ignore one instance which has
>   age 17.

I want to don't return this group if any of its member is under 18.

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's easier to identify the groups you don't want, so I'd probably do

```rb
class Group < ApplicationRecord
  # ...
  scope :mature, -> {
    excluded_ids = UserGroup.joins(:users).where('users.age <= ?', 18).select(:group_id)
    where.not(id: excluded_ids)
  }
end
```

and then

```rb
=> Group.mature.to_a
```

will produce exactly one DB request with sub-select.

Comment: A bit of saving: `excluded_ids = UserGroup.joins(:users).where('users.age <= ?', 18).select(:group_id)`

Comment: Thanks, though is the best possible way? we cant't achieve in single query?

Comment: @MuhammadFaisalIqbal sorry, not that I can think of. Note that the first query does a `select` or `pluck` so it returns a small payload, not a full set of matching records.

Comment: ok, and @PavelMikhailyuk I tried to see difference in select vs pluck but not able to understand how it 'll better here. can you explain a little?

Comment: `select` is better one because it returns a _relation_ instead of _array_ in the `pluck` case. So, when you use `select` you get your `mature_groups = ` in exactly _one_ DB query (with sub-select). And when you do `pluck`, you get _two_ queries.

Comment: So, my first comment (saving) was about 1) discounting `JOIN`s 2) single query.

Comment: @PavelMikhailyuk thanks, but not sure if am doing some thing wrong, its still generate 2 queries like first line does "UserGroup Load (0.8ms)" and second one "Group Load (1.9ms)", am I looking in wrong way?

Comment: Yes, just do _not_ test it in `irb`(`pry`) line by line. Either run a method with the whole code, OR run lines like `excluded_ids = UserGroup.joins ... ; 1`.

Comment: @MuhammadFaisalIqbal Edited Steve's answer - better than 1000 words :)